# Premature end of script

Tags: php, opencart, fastcgi, plesk

After upgrade my php version 5.3.3 , I got Internal Server Error 500, and i checked over Plesk 11x Cent-os 6.5 error_log , i got these errors :

[Thu Jun 05 18:29:27 2014] [error] [client 176.42.226.192] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: https://www.domain.net/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/update&token=480c3bdd9e4848efad346ac05eb423b5&product_id=2068

[Thu Jun 05 18:33:56 2014] [warn] [client 176.42.226.192] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 45 seconds, referer: https://www.domain.net/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/update&token=480c3bdd9e4848efad346ac05eb423b5&product_id=2068

[Thu Jun 05 18:33:56 2014] [error] [client 176.42.226.192] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: https://www.domain.net/admin/index.php?route=catalog/product/update&token=480c3bdd9e4848efad346ac05eb423b5&product_id=2068

The function that gives error :

```
public function update() {

    $this->language->load('catalog/product');

    $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {

    var_dump($this->request);

        exit();

        $this->model_catalog_product->editProduct($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post);

        $this->openbay->productUpdateListen($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post);

        $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter_name'])) {
            $url .= '&filter_name=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['filter_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter_model'])) {
            $url .= '&filter_model=' . urlencode(html_entity_decode($this->request->get['filter_model'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter_price'])) {
            $url .= '&filter_price=' . $this->request->get['filter_price'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter_quantity'])) {
            $url .= '&filter_quantity=' . $this->request->get['filter_quantity'];
        }   

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter_status'])) {
            $url .= '&filter_status=' . $this->request->get['filter_status'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        var_dump($this->request);

        exit();

        $this->redirect($this->url->link('catalog/product', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . $url, 'SSL'));
    }

    $this->getForm();
}
```

After putting exit(); command just after

```
if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm())
```

it var_dump works well but after validation conditions , exit(); and var_dump does not executing,  somewhere in conditions gives 500 error

Comment: Now we know who's the registrant for `domain.com` - wow. Now, how about some code?

Comment: @Fred-ii- is it related about code ? or something mis server configuration over php.ini or something BOM problems ?

Comment: It's hard to say, it could be anything. Have you checked your logs? If you have some code to share, it could help. It could even be a curly/smart quote, missing something; again, could be anything.

Comment: Google "Premature end of script" for some blog posts and mail archives with possible cause/solution tips.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I edited my question, please check it .

Comment: I think it's class-related and I'm not the guy for this. But that's what it seems to be, and you might have something inside another file that could be at fault, in one of your classes that could have changed since the update.

Comment: Hi there, the problem seems to be with this function  $this->openbay->productUpdateListen($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post);
 other validations seems normal the error you are getting is header related. What OC version are you using?

Comment: @Fred-ii- `domain.(com|net|.*)` is commonly and widely used for *dummy URLs* and for URL censoring ;-)

Comment: What is this **`$this->openbay->productUpdateListen($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post);`** - especially I am curious about how is the `openbay` registered.

Answer (score -2):

it's true ... sorry. analyzing their function actually seems to be wrong. Since it was made an upgrade of PHP should probably be some setting in php.ini. Increase max_execution_time, memory_limit, output_buffering. try: print_r(error_get_last()); exit();

Comment: I got php 5.3.3 and error is Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: . I have Plesk 11x running through Cent-OS 6.5 as i wrote in my questions.

Comment: it's true ... sorry. analyzing their function actually seems to be wrong. Since it was made an upgrade of PHP should probably be some setting in php.ini. Increase max_execution_time, memory_limit, output_buffering. try: print_r(error_get_last()); exit();